# Truth value of these statements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Am I right in the following?

a) $$∀x ∈ N: ∀y ∈ N: x + y ≥ 0$$

**T**

b) $$∀x ∈ Z: ∀y ∈ Z: x + y ≥ 0$$

**F**

c) $$∀x ∈ Z: ∃y ∈ Z: x + y ≥ 0$$

**T**

Comment: Yes, it seems everything you have written is correct.